# Header text not appearing on mobile

Tags: html, css, web, squarespace

**[This is how it looks on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5znN.jpg)

[This is how it looks on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaMx6.png)

The header text does not appear on mobile. Any reason why?
I'm new to css. Below is the custom css I've added:
Thanks in advance.**

*Update* -
Added the html as well. Sorry, bear with me, can't seem to add more than a few lines of codes without more description.

*Update 2* - 
Added 2 screenshots of how a button looks on mobile with 2 different fonts. Why is it one doesn't appear?

[Click here to see screenshot of button with Gotham font - doesn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOLyg.png)
[Click here to see screenshot of button with Grumpy font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlWbi.png)

```css
//ADDING FONTS//

@font-face {    
font-family: 'GRUMPY';       
src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e671ddf602f01370b0eff04/t/5e703047b02883185a0fed19/1584410695558/Grumpy+Black48.otf');  
 }

@font-face {    
font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';       
src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e671ddf602f01370b0eff04/t/5e70326a8ddd1113d8ead425/1584411243146/GothamMedium.ttf');  }

@font-face {    
font-family: 'GOTHAM-BOOK';       
src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e671ddf602f01370b0eff04/t/5e703fe01356f60cd4de3565/1584414689162/GothamBook.ttf');  }

//SETTING TYPEFACE//

h1 {
  font-family: 'GRUMPY';
  font-size: 7vh;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';
  font-size: 7vh;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';
  font-size: 5vh;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';
  font-size:4vh;
}

p {
  font-family:'GOTHAM-BOOK';
  font-size: 2.2vh !important;
}

body {
  font-family:'GOTHAM-BOOK';
  font-size: 2.2vh !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12" data-type="page-section" id="page-section-5e6f422ffd82d42cb292dd66">
    <div class="row sqs-row">
      <div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12">
        <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-592cf9f5c18d780deacb">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;white-space:pre-wrap;"><strong>New Beach Collection</strong></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53" id="block-4b700310cae983fab358">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <div class="sqs-block-button-container--center" data-animation-role="button" data-alignment="center" data-button-size="small">
              <a href="/shop" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element">Shop Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML also? As far as I see the problem doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: Maybe your font is too big and your overflow is hidden? Impossible to say without the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue why the Heading is hidden in Mobile, might be because you have unknowingly added CSS to hide them.
I have added inline css to the heading element. Kindly check the below code and see if this solves the issue.
It would be better if you can share the website URL. Seems like you have password-protected the website. If you can remove the password protection for homepage, we can solve this issue in minutes then you can re enable it.

```html
<style>
//ADDING FONTS//

@font-face {    
font-family: 'GRUMPY';       
src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e671ddf602f01370b0eff04/t/5e703047b02883185a0fed19/1584410695558/Grumpy+Black48.otf');  
}

@font-face {    
font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';       
src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e671ddf602f01370b0eff04/t/5e70326a8ddd1113d8ead425/1584411243146/GothamMedium.ttf');  }

@font-face {    
font-family: 'GOTHAM-BOOK';       
src: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e671ddf602f01370b0eff04/t/5e703fe01356f60cd4de3565/1584414689162/GothamBook.ttf');  }

//SETTING TYPEFACE//

h1 {
  font-family: 'GRUMPY';
  font-size: 7vh;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';
  font-size: 7vh;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';
  font-size: 5vh;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'GOTHAM-MEDIUM';
  font-size:4vh;
}

p {
  font-family:'GOTHAM-BOOK';
  font-size: 2.2vh !important;
}

body {
  font-family:'GOTHAM-BOOK';
  font-size: 2.2vh !important;
}
</style>
<div class="content">

  <div class="sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12" data-type="page-section" id="page-section-5e6f422ffd82d42cb292dd66">
    <div class="row sqs-row">
      <div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12">
        <div class="sqs-block html-block sqs-block-html" data-block-type="2" id="block-592cf9f5c18d780deacb">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <h2 style="display:block !important;visibility:visible !important;text-align:center;white-space:pre-wrap;"><strong>New Beach Collection</strong></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sqs-block button-block sqs-block-button" data-block-type="53" id="block-4b700310cae983fab358">
          <div class="sqs-block-content">
            <div class="sqs-block-button-container--center" data-animation-role="button" data-alignment="center" data-button-size="small">
              <a href="/shop" class="sqs-block-button-element--small sqs-block-button-element">Shop Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Now its working fine. Check it.
I have edited my answer with screenshots taken from my mobile and desktop responsive view

Comment: Hi Rajeev, I realised that's because I changed the text format into a h1 instead of h2. But now some of my other texts are missing - e.g. newsletter button. I'm starting to suspect this as an issue with the font as the disappearing texts are all GOTHAM-MEDIUM. Any solution to this?

Comment: i dont see anything missing. can you share the screenshot of the missing item?

Comment: Join this Chat Room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/210211/header-text-issue?tab=general

Comment: Hey Rajeev, sorry I don't have 20 reputation to speak in the chat. I'll update on the thread!

Comment: Hi,
I checked in the mobile. Its working fine. But when i click the button, it turns blank because you've set the button color on FOCUS to be WHITE. Thats the issue here.